# ILMerge DLL: Assembly not merged in correctly, still listed as an external reference

Tags: c#, build-process, assemblies, ilmerge

In the build process for a .NET C# tool, I have been using ILMerge to merge the assemblies into a single exe.

I added a new class library recently, and now the ILMerge is failing. I have remembered to tell it to merge in the new DLL!

It is now giving me this error, which I don't really understand:

> ILMerge.Merge: The assembly
>   'DataObjects' was not merged in
>   correctly. It is still listed as an
>   external reference in the target
>   assembly.

All of the assembly references I have done using 'project' references, and it has not failed in the past.

Can anyone explain this error for me, or suggest a workaround please?

Comment: Does it tell you the source assembly? Or can you use .Net reflector to find that?

Comment: It is literally just outputting the line above.
A few of the assemblies that I am trying to merge reference the 'DataObjects' assembly, but this has been the case for quite a while, and it is only when adding a new assembly that references it that I am getting the above error.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer - hope it helps!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had to use the `/closed` argument. According to the [official docs](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge/blob/master/ilmerge-manual.md#26-closed):

> Closed
>
> When this is set before calling Merge,
>   then the "transitive closure" of the
>   input assemblies is computed and added
>   to the list of input assemblies. An
>   assembly is considered part of the
>   transitive closure if it is
>   referenced, either directly or
>   indirectly, from one of the originally
>   specified input assemblies and it has
>   an external reference to one of the
>   input assemblies, or one of the
>   assemblies that has such a reference.
>   Complicated, but that is life...

Comment: To add a bit of context, adding the /closed switch to the ilmerge command may 'work' but the underlying problem is that there is one (or more) unmerged assembly that holds a direct reference to something you're trying to merge out of existence. You probably want to check if this was intentional and maybe add the assembly explicitly to the merge operation - or get rid of the reference if it wasn't, to avoid future confusion...

Answer (score 8):

I got a similar error message when trying to publish a web app that merged all outputs to a single assembly:

> An error occurred when merging assemblies: ILMerge.Merge: The target assembly lists itself as an external reference.

This happens if the assembly name you are merging to matches the assembly name of the web application under `Properties > Application`.  Changing the output assembly name should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and it pointed to the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk reference which I was merging into the single dll. The problem was fixed when I set another reference, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment to merge into the dll as well. Funny thing is in a separate project I had the 1st reference merging and the 2nd deployment dll not merging & it did not complain at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly @HughJeffner's answer as an image. It took me a while & some tries to replicate the instructions.

[image: Locations of the fields that should NOT be identical.]

Comment: is this vs2022?

Answer (score 0):

While publishing select 'Do not merge' from configure and than publish the Project

Answer (score 0):

I got this error for `System.Memory.dll` which was odd. In the context of merging and deploying a Dynamics CRM Plugin dll.

**I actually just ignored it and deployed my Merged DLL...** trusting that Dynamics CRM's Plugin context would provide it when it's deployed.

The `MergedPlugin.dll` was still built even with the error about `System.Memory.dll`. So I just deployed the Plugin to CRM, and it worked.