# Embed DLL into Exe

Tags: c#, build

Is there a way to build my exe that other references will be embedded? for example. the System.Data.Entity.dll.

Comment: Be careful about licensing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ILMerge - Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) is a utility that can be used to merge multiple .NET assemblies into a single assembly. It is freely available for use from the Tools & Utilities page at the Microsoft Research page.

Comment: Yeah. I did some research about that. But it fails on merging. Can you site an example for this? or things I need to assure first before merging? Thanks for fast response though

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Can you edit your question and tell us what the error is? Thanks. Looking around the "fails on merging" seems be quite well known: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807652/ilmerge-dll-not-merged-in-correctly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376/ilmerge-best-practices

Answer (score 1):

Optionally:

If you are using Visual Studio w/Nuget, you can simply set your needed reference to 'copy local = true' and install [Fody.Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura).

You can refine things a bit using a simple xml file, per the documentation provided on the project page (as well as tidy-up your build directory if desired).

Comment: I second this.  Once it's installed, it automatically combines everything into the exe.  A classic case of "it just works".

Answer (score 0):

One way is to embed the dll as a resource, then [extract it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/f4caca30-67ed-48b9-ba5a-8e8e5df82f8f) to the filesystem at run time and then [dynamically load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) it.

Although it is hard to imagine why you would need to do this - there are [various](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/promolanding/10909.htm) [installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [mechanisms](http://wixtoolset.org/) that allow you to package multiple files and deploy them together.