# Merge/Embed multiple assemblies with/into a monogame app that depends on them

Tags: c#, .net, embed, monogame, ilmerge

I have made an app in monogame. When I build it, I get something that looks like this:
[image]
and my app structure looks like this:
[image]
The highlighted "Program.cs" file is the one that contains the main entry point for the application, it look like this:

```
using System;

namespace MapEditor
{
#if WINDOWS || LINUX
    /// <summary>
    /// The main class.
    /// </summary>
    public class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var game = new MapEdit())
                game.Run();
        }
    }
 #endif
}
```

I would like to merge/embed these within MapEditor.exe.
Here are the things I have tried:

- Using [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/) method.

  - The error I get is that the app still can't find the file.
  - I have also tried the CodeProject version of this
- Using ILMerge through the command line

  - This leads to an error is will place [here](https://pastebin.com/RbusRaty), this also contains the command I used.
- Using the GUI version of ILMerge doesn't work

  - It throws an error about it not being compatible with .Net 4.7
- Using the batch script for ILMerge

  - It just puts the arguments for ILMerge onto the command line

Very many thanks to any help received, I have been trying to do this for the past... 4 hours?

PS: All the assemblies you see in the image below are .net assemblies.

Comment: Have you attempted ILMerge with `/closed` per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807652/ilmerge-dll-assembly-not-merged-in-correctly-still-listed-as-an-external-refer

Comment: @Shawn Rakowski Yes